# How can I blur the background and still be able to clip the unblurred background to the text?

Tags: css

[This](https://codepen.io/Hello911/pen/wqJWXW?editors=1100) is the closest I can get to. But instead of the text being black. I want it to have the UNBLURRED background clipped to it.

Attempt 1:

```css
*{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
/*Centering*/
html,body{
  height:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.box{
  height:100%;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
/*Clip text*/
.item{
  font-size:250px;
  z-index:1;
}
.box{
 background:url('https://media.timeout.com/images/103444978/image.jpg');
  background-size:cover;
}
/*Blurring*/
.box::before{
  content:'';
  background:inherit;
  filter:blur(10px);
  position:absolute;
  top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0;
  margin:-20px;
}
```

```html
<div class='box'>
  <div class='item'>NYC</div>
</div>
```

The problem seems to be the conflict between the z-index:1 set on .item class, and the -webkit-background-clip:text; property. You cannot have the 2 together, otherwise, the screen will be blank. The z-index:1 is used to put the text in front of the blurred bacground.

[This](https://codepen.io/Hello911/pen/prebYd?editors=0100) is where I try to put the blurring and clipping effect together. I commented out the z-index:1 in .item class, so the page won't go blank.

Attemp 2:

```css
*{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
/*Centering*/
html,body{
  height:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.box{
  height:100%;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
/*Clip text*/
.item{
  font-size:250px;
  /*z-index:1;*/
}
.box{
 background:url('https://media.timeout.com/images/103444978/image.jpg');color:#21537a;/*text color for nonwebkit*/
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  background-size:cover;
  -webkit-background-clip:text;
}
/*Blurring*/
.box::before{
  content:'';
  background:inherit;
  filter:blur(10px);
  position:absolute;
  top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0;
  margin:-20px;
}
```

```html
<div class='box'>
  <div class='item'>NYC</div>
</div>
```

Comment: is this what you're going for? https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/QMpKEa?editors=1100

Comment: Holy shit yes. You should make it an answer

Comment: Awesome! submitted an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the same background, with the same parameters to `.box` and `.box::before`. Move `.box::before` to the background using `z-index: -1`.

**Note**: The text is unreadable with `blur(10px)`, so I've changed it to `filter: blur(15px)`.

```
.box,
.box::before {
  background: url('https://media.timeout.com/images/103444978/image.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 0;
}
```

```css
* { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
html, body { height: 100%; overflow: hidden; }

.item {
  font-size: 250px;
}

.box,
.box::before {
  background: url('https://media.timeout.com/images/103444978/image.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 0;
}

.box {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  color: #21537a; /*text color for nonwebkit*/
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
}

.box::before {
  z-index: -1;
  content: '';
  filter: blur(15px);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="item">NYC</div>
</div>
```

To blur just the text, remove the `::before` pseudo-element, and move the background clip properties and the filter to the `.item`. You'll need to give the text a bit of color, and lower the filter radius, or the effect would be almost invisible.

```css
* { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
html, body { height: 100%; overflow: hidden; }

.box,
.item {
  background: url('https://media.timeout.com/images/103444978/image.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 0;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 250px;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  filter: blur(2px);
}

.box {
  height: 100%;
  color: #21537a;
}
```

```html
<div class='box'>
  <div class='item'>NYC</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why did you add position relative on .box?

Comment: Can you explain the logic? Why are you putting z-index:-1 on the ::before rather than z-index:1 on the text to make it pop out?

Comment: Setting position `.box` makes it the stacking context of `.box::before` (since `.box` covers the screen, and did doesn't really matter in this case). Setting `z-index: -1` on the pseudo element moves it under the `.box` element (it becomes the background).

Comment: Is there a way to invert this effect so the text blurs the background but everything outside the text is sharp?

Comment: @ElendilTheTall - I've added a text blur only solution.

Comment: @OriDrori that's neat, thanks! Is there any way to make the edge of the text sharp and just blur 'inside it'?

Answer (score 1):

Just give both elements the background with `height: 100%` so that the background size will be the same for both, change `.item` to be the flex parent that center's it's content, apply the background-clip and text-fill-color to `.item` and give it a `position` so it will appear of the pseudo element of the parent.

```css
*{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
/*Centering*/
html,body, .item, .box{
  height:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.item{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
/*Clip text*/

.box {
  background:url('https://media.timeout.com/images/103444978/image.jpg');
  color:#21537a;
  background-size:cover;
}
/*Blurring*/
.box::before{
  content:'';
  background:inherit;
  filter:blur(10px);
  position:absolute;
  top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0;
  margin:-20px;
}
.item{
  font-size:250px;
  position: relative;
  background: inherit;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip:text;
}
```

```html
<div class='box'>
  <div class='item'>NYC</div>
</div>
```